# jtablesaw: how to set the font size on the legend?

Tags: java, legend, legend-properties, tablesaw

does anybody know how to set the font size in a jtablesaw legend  ?  I could not find any legend object , it seems one can only set "showLegend(true|false)" when creating a layout ...

Comment: What jtablesaw  project are you using?

Comment: I am using the core + jsplot to create a line chart ( tablesaw-core    v 0.38.1  and tablesaw-jsplot v.0.38.1 from the maven repo "tech.tablesaw" )